# Qt serial port communication from an input file; weird behavior

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I am working on programming a device using Qt C++ 5.3.2.
There is a weird behavior, which I am not able to understand.

```
QByteArray file_data;

if (!file.atEnd()) {
    file_data = file.readAll();
}

int i = 0, j = 0;
int index = 0;
QByteArray DataBuf;

j = 76;

while (true)

{
    DataBuf[0] = (j + 3);
    DataBuf[1] = 0x24;
    DataBuf[2] = 0x24;
    for (i = 0; i < j; ++i)
    {
        DataBuf[i + 3] = file_data[i + index];
        DataBuf[1] = DataBuf[1] + file_data[i + index];   //Doubt here
    }

    response.clear();
    serialPort->write(DataBuf, DataBuf[0]);

    for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
        if (serialPort->readBufferSize()>=2) {
            break;
        }
        wait(1);        //user defined function, is same as msleep(5)
    }

    qa = response.toLocal8Bit();

    if (qa.toHex() != "00cc") return;

    index += 76;

    if (j == len) break;
    if (len > 76) len -= 76;
    if (len <= 76) j = len;
}
```

This is the part of code which I am working on. The line mentioned as " Doubt here" does not work as expected.
When I run this program the value at Databuf[1] does not match the sum of the total 76 bytes of data.
The data written in Databuf[2] to Databuf[78] is totally correct, but the addition is not.
But when I change the line from DataBuf[1] = DataBuf[1] + file_data[i + index]; to DataBuf[1] = DataBuf[1] + DataBuf[i + 3]; it works properly.

What is happening here? Can anyone help please.

Comment: Accumulation of values in `char` type will surly end with overflow.

Comment: @MarekR: for the accumulation, it seems that he wants to compute the checksum.

Comment: You should check if the len (file size ?)  and j at the beginning of the while loop or you will catch an undefined behavior if len < j ( = 76 ). Note that DataBuf must be initialized before (e.g: DataBuf.resize(77) ).

Comment: If your protocole uses 16 bits checksum, you must store the sum result in DataBuf[1] and DataBuf[2], not only DataBuf[1]

Comment: QByteRef QByteArray::operator[](int i)

Comment: @MarekR, as Tung Le Thanh mentioned, Databuf[1] is calculating the checksum.

Comment: One thing I found out was, the wrong checksum which was being calculated, was may be because the half of the message is at the end of the block and the next half is at the starting of the next block. But this makes things more complicated because, how is that message is being correctly written to Databuf[2+] but the checksum is not calculated.

Comment: @TungLeThanh, Thanks for pointing it out, I will initialize DataBuf. And the checksum is 8bits, so Databuf[1] is enough.

Comment: For the checksum, I think it should work. Did you call `response = readAll();` somewhere?

Comment: yes also thought, it should not make any difference. yes I used response = readAll(); it is called when wait(1) is executed.